# Handcent SMS - privacy box backup file read

Tags: backup, privacy, handcent-sms

Is there a way to decrypt backup file of Handcent SMS privacy box? File is by default named like:

```
hcprivacy-loginName-D01M01Y01.z
```

I've lost my phone but have those backup files on my computer, although they are not in readable form. Inside, there is information I need to get. Please advise...

Comment: do you want to open these files with your computer or just restore them with a new phone?

Comment: Actually it does not matter. The point is to open a particular message within in which I saved one of my passwords.

Comment: try to extract it with winrar or 7zip, then you should be able to read the files in this archive.
if you can't, download another software.